# Reading characters into a limited buffer size

Tags: c, input, system-calls

I have a program that takes in characters and reads them into a buffer of limited size (in this case 64). If the user enters more than 64 characters, it must reject the entire input string, warn the user that they entered too many characters, and start over. If the user hits `ctrl-D`, which is an end-of-file, the program must exit.

So my design is as follows: make the actual underlying buffer 65 characters to accomodate for the newline character. If the final character is not a newline, then the user hit `ctrl-D`, so the program exits. If the buffer is filled (i.e. it contains 65 characters) and the final one isn't a newline, the program assumes that too many characters were given, so it goes into a loop and continually reads input into the buffer until it the buffer read in ends with a newline (in which case it warns the user of the limit and starts over), or it's cut short without ending in a newline (in which case the program terminates).

My question is, how can I handle the case where the user enters exactly 65 characters (or some integer multiple of 65), and then hits `ctrl-D`? As the program currently stands, when the buffer is filled and doesn't end in a newline, it assumes there was an overflow, but in this case I would like the program to terminate. How can I make the program terminate upon receiving a scalar multiple of 65 characters and then a `ctrl-D`?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE ( 65 )


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    char* prompt = "myshell->";
    char* tooMany = "Max characters (64) exceeded.\n";
    int numInput;
    int done = 0;
    char input[ BUFSIZE ];
    while( !done ) {
        int cont = 0;

        write( STDOUT_FILENO, prompt, strlen( prompt ) );
        numInput = read( STDIN_FILENO, input, BUFSIZE );
        if( input[ numInput - 1 ] == '\n' ) {
            cont = 1;
        } else {
            if( numInput != BUFSIZE ) {
                done = 1;
                write( STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", strlen( "\n" ) );
            } else {
                int spill = 1;
                while( spill ) {
                    numInput = read( STDIN_FILENO, input, BUFSIZE );
                    if( input[ numInput - 1 ] == '\n' ) {
                        spill = 0;
                        write( STDOUT_FILENO, tooMany, strlen( tooMany ) );
                    } else {
                        if( numInput != BUFSIZE ) {
                            spill = 0;
                            done = 1;
                            write( STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", strlen( "\n" ) );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*done ingesting input. Now do something with it...*/
        if( cont ) {
            write( STDOUT_FILENO, input, numInput );
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Constraint:** I can only use the `read` and `write` functions, but not anything from `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: I believe you should not limit the input line size. Use [getline](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_getline.htm)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yea that would work, but I can only use system calls for IO.

Comment: Then ensure that you grow your buffer to always fit a line inside (perhaps using `malloc` ...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But then how does that solve the stated problem of distinguishing between a buffer overflow, and a full buffer followed by a `ctrl-D`?

Comment: After `read`, `numInput` can be negative (on error) or zero (on EOF).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's what I was counting on at first, but it won't be zero because it will instead wait for more input from the user. It only returns 0 if the user enters `ctrl-D` a second time...

Comment: `write( STDOUT_FILENO, prompt, strlen( prompt ) );` - WAT? `puts(prompt);`... And **please** use `fgets()` for reading user input, and **please** don't use whitespace inside parenthesis.

Comment: @H2CO3 `puts` and `fgets` aren't system calls..

Comment: @Ataraxia No, they are C standard library functions. How is that relevant?

Comment: @H2CO3 Because I stated a constraint in the question that I can only use system calls for input and output.

Comment: @Ataraxia Huh? `write()` and `read()` are **also** stdlib functions that wrap the system calls. `puts()` & friends do nothing else. Or are you only allowed to write inline assembly!?

Comment: @H2CO3 By system calls (I apologize if that is the incorrect term to use, but whether or not they're called system calls is irrelevant...), I mean I cannot use `stdio`. And specifically the program is to use `read` for input and `write` for output.

Comment: @Ataraxia Aham, I see. So you can't use functions from `<stdio.h>`. Okay, understood.

Answer (score 0):

You should really accept arbitrarily sized lines. Notice that reading a [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) -e.g. in a terminal- is different from reading e.g. some pipe. (Pseudo `tty`-s are a complex topic: some of the line buffering happens in kernel).

And you should have some buffering -you could often have `read` more bytes than what you need, so keep the extra bytes in the buffer for future consumption.

So you should `malloc` the buffer (and re-allocate it when too small). If you teacher don't allow `malloc`, implement your own allocator using `mmap`

Read carefully the [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) man page. Don't forget that it can return -1 on error, 0 on end-of-file, or some count on success.

Comment: Ok I clarified the question and removed some distracting elements (like mentioning that this was for a shell). I appreciate the help, but I believe I may not have made the question as clear as I could have.

Answer (score -3):

If this is really a shell then why not handle longer data entry streams?

If your buffer is limited to 65/64 bytes then code a "read/process or parse text/read parse/etc." loop.

When eventually your code receives a CTRL-D then exec the results of all your parses.

Comment: This answers "What is one way to make a shell?", but do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem I stated in the question of how to terminate execution upon receiving exactly 65 bytes followed by a `ctrl-D`?

Comment: @Ataraxia, we are talking about the difference between a programmer and a programmer analyst.  While a programmer will just do what he/she is told to do, an analyst will examine the problem's requirements and find the simplest solution that provides the most number of features.  I don't think your users are going to appreciate entering 66 chars of info. and then be told to start over!!

Comment: Yes, I agree that the character limit is too small. But unfortunately the design constraints aren't up to me in this particular situation. So I can't be a programmer analyst here..

Comment: There is no character limit, despite what someone is telling you! (unless you have not mentioned a critical fact that would change such a comment).  In theory you can issue the system call read for one character at a time.  This is coded all of the time in parsers for compilers.  If nothing else, read chars one at a time and when char count = 65 and no ctrl-d was found then punish the user.

Comment: There is to be a character limit in the program that I am tasked with making, which my program is tasked with enforcing.

Comment: Also, if I do what you suggested, how would I tell the difference between the user entering a ctrl-D at the end of the input string, and there simply being more characters that haven't been read in? (which is still just the original question that I asked).

Comment: @Ataraxia, if you read the characters as they are entered (remember a person typing is very much slower than reading ONE char), then keep reading until a CTRL-D or a new-line or some other indicator that the user has forgotten to enter CTRL-D.  Honestly, you haven't given enough technical details to make a good recommendation.  You are simply saying, in essence, solve this problem that has conflicting requirements.  In reality, completely understanding the problem usually results in a good solution.